# Rails 6 upgrading from turbolinks to turbo. How to require turbo-rails in application.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, turbolinks

I'm working on a legacy application, recently upgrades to Rails 6.0.4. The app uses `sprockets`, NOT `webpacker`.

Now I'm trying to move off of `turbolinks` and onto `turbo-rails`. The js files in this app all use sprockets require directives such as:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require turbolinks
```

I can't seem to figure out how to apply this to `turbo-rails`. I've installed the gem and removed turbolinks, but all of the documentation I've found has things like `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"`.

I'm not very knowledgeable about front end stuff, but I believe this is a different (ES6?) syntax. This app is currently on `sprockets 3.7.2` and I don't think sprockets supports ES6 until version 4. I'd like to avoid this upgrade touching more dependencies if possible...

is it possible to `//= require` turbo in the same way I currently have `//= require turbolinks`?'

Comment: I see there's a `/app/assets/javascript/turbo.js` file https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/assets/javascripts/turbo.js, it looks like you might be able to do `//= require turbo` since that's the name of the file and sprockets can lookup files inside those folders inside gems. Not sure if that would be enough though, but it should be a start

Comment: @arieljuod Thank you. Thank you, I had tried that before and it didn't seem to work with my `$(document).on("turbolinks:load"` BUT I guess the fact that there's no error during asset compilation means the file is being found. So I just tried it again, and now I'm noticing this error in web console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module` pointing at `Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`. So I guess the file *is* being found but something else is wrong??

Comment: I wouldn't expect turbo to have the same events. I would consider if you should get off Sprockets first and then switch to turbo to avoid having to do a bunch of duplicate work.

Comment: https://gorails.com/episodes/upgrade-from-turbolinks-to-hotwire-and-turbo

Comment: //= require turbo solved my issue, as I don't need or use webpack/webpacker

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `turbo-rails`, you have to have the asset pipeline set up to transpile ES6. This isn't possible with my version of `sprockets` (3.7.2), so I have two options:

- upgrade to sprockets 4
- switch to using `webpacker` for the Javascript portion of the asset pipeline

With one of these in place, I should be able to use `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"`.

Comment: Even with a newer version of sprockets, you need to use //= require turbo not import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

Comment: @SeanMitchell Does `//= require turbo` work in Rails 7? I'm trying that with sprockets-rails v3.4.0 (current) and no transpiler/webpacker/importmap, and rails does not find `turbo`

Comment: I had this same issue.  `//= require turbo` worked for me on Sprockets (4.2.1).